# How can I get Chrome Browser Version running now with Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a application using selenium, and I want to know actual chrome browser version installed, before running Chrome Driver to avoid any Exception for compatibility reason. I know I can use `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")` then `driver.capabilities['browserVersion']` to show version but if Chrome Driver version differ from actual chrome browser version that's raise an exception.

Thanks

**Edited:** 
Actually I found the answer for myself, the solution I found:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def get_version_via_com(filename):
    parser = Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    try:
        version = parser.GetFileVersion(filename)
    except Exception:
        return None
    return version

if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = [r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
             r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"]
    version = list(filter(None, [get_version_via_com(p) for p in paths]))[0]
    print(version)
    # result: 80.0.3987.122
```

PS: I think people don't understand my question at the beginning and I'm sorry for my english

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, it would be much appreciated it if you share it. Thanks.

Comment: @mikey Hi guy, Thank you for understanding my question, the solution was posted you can check now and ask me if there is something need to be clear.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, saved me some time :). In fact, you just need Dispatch: win32com.client.Dispatch.Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileVersion(paths[1]), resulted in '80.0.3987.116' in my Win10 box.

Comment: @mikey Thanks for correcting me, I have remove `netifaces` module, because I played around with many tests in one file so I forgot to removed redundant module

Comment: I've added the solution, since I couldn't provide an answer due to thread being closed.

Comment: Get this package, this will help you out:
[link](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/) , then call:
`gc_version = chromedriver_autoinstaller.get_chrome_version()
print(gc_version)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using selenium, then you can get the ***chrome*** browser version using the `driver.capabilities` dictionary.

```
driver.capabilities['browserVersion']
```

Earlier version of chromedriver stored the chrome browser version `driver.capabilities['version']`. If you want to get chrome browser version without having to worry about this, you can use the below code.

```
if 'browserVersion' in driver.capabilities:
    print(driver.capabilities['browserVersion'])
else:
    print(driver.capabilities['version'])
```

Comment: I know that, but when using selenium: `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")` the program can be crashed before running `driver.capabilities['version']` (reason is chrome version not compatilble, so I must check chrome version first)

Comment: @leminhnguyenHUST Are you looking for a method to get current chrome browser version without loading the `webdriver` ?

Comment: Ohh right, I think we can use Python's library likes `request`, is it feasiable ? (my own opinion)

Comment: @leminhnguyenHUST That really depends upon your requirement. For this question, i think my answer is sufficient.